# Gamma regression R GLM vs SAS GENMOD

Tags: r, sas, regression, gamma

I am trying to replicate gamma regression that I have in SAS with R. Unfortunately, I get completely different parameter estimation and I do not have any idea what could cause that. I was looking for answer to my problem on SO but I didn't find anything that cover it.

My SAS code is:

```
proc genmod data=data;
class var1 factor1 ;
Make 'Obstats' Out=Outdata_G;
model answer = var2 factor1 var3/
offset= offset dist=Gamma link=log obstats;
run;
```

I see that the var1 is used in class statement, but isn't used in model statement - can it change the results? (I cannot rerun the code).

What I've done in R is:

```
glm(answer~var2+factor1+var3, data =(data), offset = offset, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
```

What could cause differences in results from those two pices of code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not enough information to go by. Can you post some data that reproduces this behavior along with model outputs from SAS and R?

Comment: Ok, for now I found that adding this:
"class var1 factor1 ;" change results. After geting rid of this only intercept is different. Does someone know if SAS & R present interscept differently in gamma regression? 

@RomanLuštrik Unfortunatelly I couldn't post any real data, I can make some artificial data, but I am not sure if it's going to help something. The problem is  that I do not have direct access to SAS

Comment: SAS and R have different default treatments of factor variables.

Comment: Use SAS UE or SAS for Academics on Demand, both are free especially if this is research or academia. See Analytics U. The CLASS statement should only affect the results IF there is missing values in that variable. For comparisons, review the default settings for PROC GENMOD vs the defaults for GLM - you'll likely find the difference there.

Comment: Without a `class` statement, SAS will treat numeric variables as continuous.  Secondly, by default SAS constructs a different dummy variable matrix for factors than R does.  Try using the `param=glm` option in the class statement and see if that makes a difference.